# Remotely start VLC w/Salt Stack

Tags: windows-7, command-line, vlc-media-player, powershell-3.0

Using Salt Stack, how does one remotely start a Windows program on the console screen?

In other words, from my Salt Master (CentOS based), I want to push this sort of command to Windows 7 (with Salt Minion) and have VLC automatically start.  e.g. from *nix shell

salt 'Win7-laptop' cmd.run '""C:\Program Files (x86)\videolan\vlc.exe"'

Is there a certain command or switch that I must run?  Or do I need to use something like psexec or Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [Invoke-Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx) 
Runs commands or expressions on the local computer.

Comment: Instead of just posting a link and one sentence, please give more context, some examples, etc.